# System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.' on static class

Tags: uwp, .net-6.0, winui-3

I'm using inside my static setup class the following method in my Winui3 App:

```
private static async void CheckDocumentsCopyDialog(string targetPath)
    {
        var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse();
        ContentDialog checkDocumentsCopy = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = Constants.App.Name + " " + resourceLoader.GetString("MsgSetupCheckDocumentHeader"),
            Content = resourceLoader.GetString("MsgSetupCheckDocumentsCopy") + " " + targetPath + ".",
            CloseButtonText = "Ok"
        };
        await checkDocumentsCopy.ShowAsync();
    }
```

As far as i know it follows Microsofts WinUI3 documentation. But i'm getting:

[image]

Maybe anyone knows, what i can do to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps this can help? https://github.com/microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery/issues/605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `XamlRoot` property of the `ContentDialog` to a valid `XamlRoot`.

The easiest way to do this from a static method would be to make the `m_window` field in the `App.xaml.cs` file `internal` and then access the window's `XamlRoot` using this field, e.g.:

```
...
checkDocumentsCopy.XamlRoot = (App.Current as App)?.m_window.Content.XamlRoot;
await checkDocumentsCopy.ShowAsync(ContentDialogPlacement.InPlace);
```

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    ...
    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        m_window = new BlankWindow2();
        m_window.Activate();
    }

    internal Window m_window;
}
```

Comment: Wgere do you get the BlankWindow2 class from? In addition, Visual Studio says, that Window does not have the Property Content for me